# How to extract an API token from a dictionary and store it in a variable?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.9 and using http.client to authenticate and generate a token. When I send the request, I get this response:

```py
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJ","user":{"id":99,"username":"mail@mail.com","tenantUuid":"-888-888-52558-878745"}
```

How can I extract the token part and store it in a variable that I can use later on?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `data` holds the dictionary, you could do:

```py
token = data["token"]
```

Comment: I added this after the data line as below
data = res.read()
token = (data["token"])
but I got this error. Is there anything that I'm missing? 
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: What is `type(data)`?

Comment: Its a response string 
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

Comment: It's a string? Pretty weird if it's mentioning byte indices.

Answer (score 0):

For consistency, if the token is missing you should use a get statement to avoid a potential exception. `get` accepts a default value if no 'token' key is found.

```py
data = myRequestFn(inputs, here)
token = data.get('token','default_variable_here')
```